# How to use do_action user_register hook in WP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a new User with wp_insert_user() function in an AJAX call. After that I need to add the phone number as custom field, so I need to use the wordpress hook user_register and I don't know how to use it.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_register', 'register_user');
add_action('wp_ajax_register', 'register_user');
function registrar_cliente(){
    if(isset($_POST['dataForPHP'])){
        $phone = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['dataForPHP'][0]);
        $name =  wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['dataForPHP'][1]);
        $email =  wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['dataForPHP'][2]);

        $userdata = [//adding data];
        $user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);
    }
}
```

How can I use now `do_action( 'user_register', int $user_id, array $userdata )` in order to insert $phone to the user in a custom field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the value of the custom field in [user_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/).

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_register', 'register_user' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_register', 'register_user' );

function register_user() {
    $phone = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $_POST['dataForPHP'][0] );
    $name  = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $_POST['dataForPHP'][1] );
    $email = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $_POST['dataForPHP'][2] );

    // $userdata = [adding data];
    $user_id   = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
    $user_meta = update_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone_no', $phone );
    if ( isset( $user_id ) ) {
        echo 'User registered';
    }
}
```

**Code for adding extra fields in Edit User Section:**

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );

function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) {
    ?>
        <h3><?php _e( 'Extra profile information', 'blank' ); ?></h3>

        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th><label for="phone_no"><?php _e( 'Phone Number' ); ?></label></th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="phone_no" id="phone_no"
                        value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'phone_no', true ) ); ?>"
                        class="regular-text" /><br />
                    <span class="description"><?php _e( 'Please enter your phone number.' ); ?></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php
}
```

**Code for saving extra fields details in the database from the edit screen(If you want to change value from edit screen):**

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone_no', $_POST['phone_no'] );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to register and enter the user.

```
/**
* User registration
*/

function prefix_register_user()
{
    $userdata  = array(
        'user_login'  => $email,
        'user_pass'   => $random_password,
        'user_email'  => $email,
        'first_name'  => $first_name,
        'last_name'   => $surname,
        'role'            => 'author',
    );
    $userid = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
    if ( !is_wp_error( $userid ) ) { // check if insert was successful
        update_user_meta( $userid, 'billing_phone', '+98' ); // add woocommerce account phone number
        $user_data = get_user_by("id", $userid);
        prefix_login_user($user_data);
        wp_redirect(get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id')));
    }

}

/**
* loggedin the registered user to the dashboard
*/

function prefix_login_user($user)
{
    wp_set_current_user($user->ID, $user->user_login);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
    do_action('wp_login', $user->user_login, $user);
}
```